# Jasmine: TypeError - Binary8 is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test a set of prototypes af have made in JavaScript with Jasmine. However I keep getting the follow error: `TypeError: Binary8 is not a constructor`. The code for the prototype looks like this:

```
function Binary8(value) {
   // assert(value < 255, "value must be between 0 and 255");
    this.storage = new Uint8Array(1);
    (this.storage)[0] = value;
    this.value = function (){return (this.storage[0])};
}
```

And when I do this `var temp = new Binary8(0x16);` or `var temp2 = new Binary8(18);` in a tools such as JS BIN, it works flawlessly. However, when I try to use the code in jasmine I get the previously mentioned error. 
Can someone please help me understand, what is wrong?

Side comment the above is an excerpt of the prototype definition and the file it is defined within. When I test in JS Bin I loaded the full content and the same for Jasmine

The specification file:

```
describe("Binary8 TEST", function() {
    var Alert = require('../../../cc-helpers.js');
    var Binary8 = require('../../../finite_fields/binary8');
    var BinaryTable =  require('../../../finite_fields/binary8_table.js');



  beforeEach(function() {
      console.log("New test");
  });

  it("Add two numbers", function() {
      var first_field = new Binary8(0x14); // 0d20 =  0x0001 0100
      var second_field = new Binary8(0x20); // 0d32 = 0x0010 0000
      // --------------------
      // Expect value:      |
      // 0x0001 0100        |
      // ^                  |
      // 0x0010 0000        |
      // 0c0011 0100 = 0d52 |
      // --------------------
      var result = (ff_add(first_field, second_field)).value() == 52;
      expect(result).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

And I run the test by executing `jasmine binary8spec.js`

Comment: Do you use a module loader (RequireJS, Browserify, Webpack, Angular ...)? How do you execute the tests (A HTML file, Build tools like Grunt, Gulp, Karma)? You should provide the _whole spec file code boiled down to the bare minimum_ (one `describe()`, `it()`, `expect()` should suffice).

Comment: @try-catch-finally I have add the information you ask for

Comment: I guess that if you never `return this;` in the end of your `Binary8` function, it will never act as a `constructor`...

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ just weird that it works in JS BIn then :) But I will try and check it

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ nope that gives the same result

Comment: If you are using `requirejs`, you should take a look to this article: https://www.airpair.com/jasmine/posts/javascriptintegrating-jasmine-with-requirejs-amd  It seems taht your module is not in the same "format" as expected by `requirejs`

Comment: Can I avoid using requireJS ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ hmmm this is annoying :/

Comment: This is a good question. I don't have a signicative exerience with `jasmine`

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ found the solution I was missing this: `module.exports = Binary8;` in my Binary8 definition :/

Answer (score 2):

The solution for the problem was to add `module.exports = Binary8;` to the end of the `Binary8` definition. However, free functions are not registered.